# How do I find only the first occurrence of a phrase that has another duplicate

Tags: regex, notepad++, duplicates

I have a document like this:

```
blah blah blah blah
There's a comedian called adam sandler who is funny
yada yada yada yada
There's a comedian called adam sandler who is funny
la la la la la la
```

I want to replace *just* the first occurrence of `adam sandler` with `jerry seinfeld`

Of course, if it was just in one document, it would be easy, but I need to match a similar pattern in hundreds of docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following regex, be sure `.` matches newline is checked ..

```
Find: \A(.*?)adam sandler(.*)\z
Replace: \1jerry seinfeld\2
```

Then you can use "Replace All in All Opened Documents"

Answer (score 1):

I think notepad ++ would support `\K`

```
(?s)^.*?\K\badam sandler\b
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/mM3xS0/2)

Replace the matched name with `jerry seinfeld`

**OR**

```
(?s)^(.*?)\badam sandler\b
```

Replace the match with `\1jerry seinfeld`

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/mM3xS0/3)

Comment: Unfortunately, when I do that and "Replace All" it matches all occurrences. It might be a Notepad++ limitation, so I'm open to any suggestion on how to do this on Windows machine on multiple files within a folder.

Comment: is there any option like `Replace` only?

Comment: Yes, but I'm ultimately trying to "Replace in all opened documents". When I tested that with just two opened documents, it replaced all instances of the match.

Comment: did you turn on the dotall mode? But i think this `(?s)` would do that.